# JavaScript - Linkedin API - Unable to GET profile info for other people

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-api

I am new to the Linkedin API and I am trying to get basic profile information about some one from the API but I don't get anything back. Here is what I get on running the code {"_total":0}. Help would be appreciated

This is the code. I am unsure what the mistake is :

```
       function onLinkedInLoad() {
        alert('call');
        IN.User.authorize(onLinkedInAuth);
    }


    function onLinkedInAuth() {

        IN.API.Profile("Other Person")
        .fields(["firstName", "lastName", "headline", "summary"])
        .result(function(result) {
          alert(JSON.stringify(result)); });
        }

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key:   ###############
    authorize: true
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
</script>
<h1 align="center" onClick="">Linkedin App </h1>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This `onLoad: onLinkedInLoad` is not proper syntax. Need to either use single variables `var x = y;` or wrap in an object `var x = { onLoad: 123 };`.

Comment: Firstly, there should be nothing inside the script tag which references the in.js file. That data should be elsewhere. Secondly, you REALLY need to obscure your API key before it gets exploited.

Comment: @ManoDestra  Thanks for the feedback :) . For the reference to in.js - I just copied that from the Linkedin Developer website.

Comment: Bizarre. Checked it and they are using those properties in that way. Very poor on LinkedIn's part. A highly improper use of the script tag. From the [documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk).